# R group_by return number of largest unique type

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have this data set:

```
df <-  data.frame(c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
  c('c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'f')
    ) %>% setNames(c('type', 'value'))

   type value
1     a     c
2     a     c
3     a     d
4     a     e
5     a     f
6     a     c
7     b     e
8     b     f
9     b     f
10    b     f
11    b     g
12    b     h
13    b     f
```

I'd like to perform some kind of command as follows:

```
df %>% group_by(type) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(largest_group_size))
```

This would ideally produce a table with the largest number of any value for a and b.

```
  type largest_group_size
1    a                  3
2    b                  4
```

This table would have:

- 3 for a, because there are 3 values of c for a, and c is the largest group for a
- 4 for b, because there are 4 values of f for b, and f is the largest group for b

Ideally, I'd like to go a step further and calculate the percentage that the largest group is of the whole by type. So (largest_group_size / n()).

Answer (score 2):

In two `group_by` steps:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(type, value) %>% 
  summarise(groups = n()) %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  summarise(largest_group = max(groups),
            as_percentage = largest_group / sum(groups))
```

This gives:

```
  type  largest_group as_percentage
  <fct>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 a                 3         0.5  
2 b                 4         0.571
```

There is probably a more efficient way, but this is how I would do this in a hurry.

Comment: This is a good solution for the specific small example problem I created. I should have clarified that in reality, the command I want is one that would generalize to many columns, e.g. a table with columns: type, val_1, val_2, val_3, ... val_n.

Comment: @Jim It's unclear how your problem generalises to a case with multiple value columns. Do you mean you want the largest group / percentage for *each* value column, or across *all* value columns?

Comment: @CMcMaster I believe `summarise()` only removes a single level of grouping, so you may not need the second `group_by()` call as it should still be grouped by "type" at that point, with the first `summarise()` only removing the "value" grouping.

Comment: @Wil Good point! I tend to put in the second `group_by()` for clarity, because that is a property that I do not find intuitive.

@Jim Could you be more explicit about whether you want the maximum in each value column, or across all value columns? The former could be solved with `summarise_at()` and the latter with a `gather()` function.